# CMake is replacing my Makefile and building the wrong executables. Cannot obtain correct executables

Tags: c++, makefile, build, cmake

I am trying to compile plotting scripts in Yarr. I want to turn these files into executables. 
The steps I am following are here: https://yarr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rootscripts/#root-scripts. This actually just points to a single step, taken after cloning the Yarr repository.

The steps I am taking are:

1. In my home directory:

`git clone https://gitlab.cern.ch/YARR/YARR Yarr`

`cd Yarr`

`checkout v1.1.1`

This gets the proper version with the plotting directory and scripts onto my computer.

2. Next, I ran:

`cd plotting`

`make`

From the documentation, after running `make`, the Makefile in `Yarr/plotting` should take all the files in `Yarr/plotting` and output them in `Yarr/plotting/build`.

The Makefile is:

```
# Simple Makefile for multiple executeables + X other files/classes
# Main files .cxx, Classes in .cpp and .h
# Define INCLUDE, LIBS and EXE accordingly

MAKEFLAGS=--warn-undefined-variables

INCLUDE = -I./. $(shell root-config --cflags) -I../src/libFei4/include -I../src/libUtil/include -I../src/libYarr/include -I../src/libSpec/include -I../src/libFe65p2/include
LIBS = $(shell root-config --libs) -L./../build/lib -lYarr

# Define compiler and flags
CXX = g++
CFLAGS = -g -O0 -Wall $(INCLUDE)
LDFLAGS = $(LIBS)

SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp) 
TARGET = $(wildcard *.cxx)
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
OOBJ = $(TARGET:.cxx=.o)
EXE = $(TARGET:.cxx=)

all: $(EXE) $(OBJ) $(OOBJ)

%.o: %.cxx $(OBJ)
    @$(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    @echo "[Compiling] $@"

%.o: %.cpp 
    @$(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    @echo "[Compiling] $@"

%: %.o
    @$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $< $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    @echo "[Linking] $@"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(OOBJ)
    rm -f $(EXE)
```

However, the output I am getting is:

```
Scanning dependencies of target Yarr
Building CXX object <many CXX objects>
Linking CXX static library ../lib/libYarr.a
Scanning dependencies of target testJson
Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/testJson.dir/tools/testJson.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/testJson
Scanning dependencies of target star_test
Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/star_test.dir/tools/star_test.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/star_test
.
.
.
```

So, `make` *is* taking files and building executables, but these are not the correct targets or executables. `make` is taking files located in `Yarr/src/tools`, building them into object files, putting the object files into `src/CMakeFiles/`, linking the object files into executables, and putting the executables into `plotting/bin`.

I wasn't sure why on earth this could be happening until I looked at the Makefile again. It appears CMake has overridden the Makefile. It has been replaced by:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.17

.
.
.

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named test

# Build rule for target.
test: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 test
.PHONY : test

# fast build rule for target.
test/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f src/CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/test.dir/build
.PHONY : test/fast



.
.
.
<The specific targets>
.
.
.
```

The targets of this Makefile are exactly those that turned into executables, like `Yarr`, `testJSon`, and `star_test`. These are the same "objects to build" as if I were to run `cmake` instead of `make`, which further suggests that CMake is overriding my Makefile.

I have deleted everything and started over many times. The same thing happens each time.

Any idea what is going on and how I can fix this? It's driving me crazy. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: What software are you trying to build? Is it [Yarr](https://github.com/Yarr/Yarr)? If so, where did the `plotting` directory come from? Is that from [the plotting-tools repository](https://gitlab.cern.ch/YARR/utilities/plotting-tools)? Note that `cmake` will by default generate Makefiles in various subdirectories. Consider making a separate `build` directory under Yarr_v1.1.1 and running `cmake ..` there. That should stop it from trampling on other makefiles.

Comment: If what you say is true (`cmake` somehow gets invoked when you type `make`), you should correct that first. Use the `type make` command to find out if `make` is somehow an alias or if it is pointing to a non-standard `make` program.

Comment: @Alan Birtles sorry about that. I have removed a lot of the second Makefile.

Comment: @Botje Yes, the software is Yarr. The plotting directory, Yarr/plotting, comes from v1.1.1 A newer version that was just release includes the plotting-tools repository, but version 1.1.1 doesn't seem to use plotting scripts or commands (not sure why the switch was made). I am using: https://gitlab.cern.ch/YARR/YARR/-/tree/v1.1.1/plotting. I did try making a new directory for Yarr v1.1.1, but I ran `make` again, not `cmake ..` . I will try this.

Comment: But yes, I do need to correct for `cmake` overtaking `make`. I ran `type make` and got: `make is hashed (/usr/bin/make)`. I am not sure what you mean  " find out if make is somehow an alias or if it is pointing to a non-standard make program" (apologies - this is new for me)

Comment: I tried making a `build` directory in my `Yarr_v1.1.1` directory and then running `cmake .../` . Unfortunately, I get the same executables to build as before. `cmake` is again going into `src/tools` and reading these files as the ones to build. It seems preset as to what files `cmake` reads. I tried moving my .cxx files into `src/tools`, but they're not read.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact steps you take (and their output) starting from a fresh clone/download so we can try to reproduce/debug it.

Comment: I have updated my question with steps and outputs. Please let me know if what I have included is not clear or if more info is needed.